# ExtJS Animate Counter from 0 to N

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a simple `Ext.Panel` item with number:

```
{
    cls: 'tableRightBorder',
    html: '<p class="someValue" onload="animateCounter()">20</p>',
    //border: '1px solid',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
}
```

And I want to make animation from 0 to 20 in this case. I've tried with onload event and this function:

```
function animateCounter() {
    var i = 0;

    var inv = setInterval(function() {
        if (i < 100)
            document.getElementsByClassName('someValue').innerHTML = ++i;
        else
            clearInterval(inv);
    }, 3000 / 100);
}
```

But this does not work. Could anyone tell me please why it is not working and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you calling the right class for getElementsByClassName?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to complete my editing.

Comment: using `DOM` manipulation in `ExtJS` is rather questionable; because this will only update the `DOM`, but not the component ...why you even use a framework? it's alike starting to create a whole new application within another application... despite it may "work". `onload="animateCounter()"` is where it already gets crappy, because there is a `listeners` configuration for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExtJS objects have a "listeners" property in which you can pass events with functions. For example:

```
{
    cls: 'tableRightBorder',
    html: '<p class="subscribersValue" onload="animateCounter()">20</p>',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    listeners: {
        onclick: () => {
            var i = 0;

            var inv = setInterval(function () {
                if (i < 100)
                    document.getElementsByClassName('subscribersValue').innerHTML = ++i;
                else
                    clearInterval(inv);
            }, 3000 / 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Surely there is an onload equivalent event for this component. Maybe afterrender?

Comment: Tried with afterrender but does not work. I get no errors though... And I can do alert but not console.log... which is strange...

Answer (score 1):

You can find a complete working example [Extjs Fiddle Counter Animation](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2phs)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Listeners',
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            items: [{
                cls: 'tableRightBorder',
                html: '<p class="subscribersValue" onload="animateCounter()">1</p>',
                width: '100%',
                id: 'myCmpId',
                height: '100%'
            }],
            listeners: {
                render: function () {
                    var i = 0;
                    var inv = setInterval(function () {
                        if (i < 20)
                            Ext.fly('myCmpId').dom.innerHTML = ++i;
                        else
                            clearInterval(inv);
                    }, 3000 / 100);
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```